# Unity2D - How to rotate a 2D object on touch/click/press

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

First of all, I'll let you know that I'm new to Unity and to coding overall (I do know some very basic javascript coding). My question: How can I rotate a 2D object (prefab) 120 degrees on a certain axis (in my case the z-axis, so it rotates like you're looking at a steering wheel) every time I touch on the screen. Right now I have it like this:

```
function TouchOnScreen ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.touches[0];
        if (touch.position.x < Screen.width/2)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,120);
            Debug.Log("RotateRight");
        }
        else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width/2)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-120);
            Debug.Log("RotateLeft");
        }
    }
}
```

This code rotates the object whenever I press on a certain side of the screen, but not how I want it to. I want it to rotate so you see the object rotating from A to B, but not (like it is now) in one frame from A to B. Also, this code lets me only rotate one time to each direction.

How can I make it that whenever I press on a certain side of the screen, that it adds or subtracts to/from the previous rotated angle, so I can keep on rotating.

NOTE: Please use javascript, and if you know a simpler code, let me know!

Help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: what you are doing here is setting a rotation on the transform... what i would recommend exploring is instead of setting `transform.rotation`, setting a "TARGET" and in your update function writing logic to animate the objects `transform.rotation` towards that target

Comment: Thanks for replying!
But could you maybe give me an example script, even though I do understand what you're explaining to me, I'm still too unskilled to change your explanation into a script :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-120);
```

You use:

```
        var lSpeed = 10.0f; // Set this to a value you like
        transform.rotation = Quaterion.Lerp ( transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-120), Time.deltaTime*lSpeed);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixes the problem of rotating from point A to B in one frame, but now the next problem is, is that I'm only able to rotate to left OR right only **one** time. So for example, if I touch the left side of the screen, it rotates left (the way I want it to), but I can't rotate it again to the left. This is the same case for touching the right side.

Comment: You cant rotate, because you're rotating to a fixed angle (like you wanted): `Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-120)` if you want to rotate beyond that simply use `Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-240)`,`Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-360)` ...etc. Perhaps now you can find your own solution

Comment: I can see the problem now @Rudolfwm . Thanks for replying, I will start looking for a way to add/subtract the degrees everytime the related side is pressed.